# How do questions become community wiki owned

Tags: discussion

In general, how do questions and answers become community wiki owned?

Specifically:

Why do we have community owned anything?

Who decides what becomes community owned?

What type of questions are eligible?

What type of answers are eligible?

Is there a type of question or answer that *must* be community owned?

Comment: if you mean "community wiki", then this question has some useful information, and a link to the main stackexchange site where it's defined:  http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2662/579

Comment: Thanks.  Does this mean that my question is a duplicate?

Comment: if that question answers yours, then yes, it's a duplicate.  but don't delete your question, please.  if you looked but couldn't find the other one, that means you weren't thinking of the available search terms, and someone else might have the same problem.  so leaving your question, but closing it, can provide another "hook" for a future searcher.

Comment: When I searched I didn't use the word "wiki" and came up empty.  To answer the questions posed I had to follow the links to the main stackexchange site answer.  Does that necessarily mean that the answer is exactly the same here on TeX.SE?  I understand that some aspects of this site are unique to the tex community.

Comment: @AFeldman: Questions can't be considered duplicates of another question on a different network. So, even though they may be *exact* duplicates, they can't be closed as such. We typically provide a short answer here with a reference to the main source (most like on [meta.se]).

Comment: @Werner In general, it seems to me that TeX.SE operates in a slightly different manner than some of the other SE sites. So I am curious what the TeX.SE take on this might be.

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/219/15925 is relevant

Comment: If you edit a question more then 25+ or something it becomes a CW. If you don't want that happening you can mention it to a moderator and they will revert it back.